There is no runtime pack available for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App Blazor WASM

Error NETSDK1082
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.  EMS.Client
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 447

I have no idea how fix this. Please help me with any advice
https://github.com/mistelltein/EmployeeManagementSystem
I try everything in other solves but nothing changed.
I use Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App btw

could you please share which .net sdk is installed on your machine? you could use this commands: dotnet --list-sdks dotnet --list-runtimes to check it. try to clear nuget cache:dotnet nuget locals all --clear. have you tried running the project with clean rebuild?

7.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
Yeas, i tried clear and rebuild project
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Same with
Microsoft.NETCore.App
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.22

first i did not find browser-wasm in your any project file. i would like to suggest you to search this line in your entire solution and if you find it comment this line. also try to reinstall the .net 7 sdk and runtime

I figured this issue out occurring with a Razor Component Library and added a fix.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53671#issuecomment-2081461812

I've found that sometimes it help to:

Remove the reference to Nuget(s) with dependencies on Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, which is often the source of the issue.
Close the VS 2022 project.
Delete the bin and the obj folder.
Restart VS 2022 and rebuild the solution.


I got this error when I downloaded the Blazor app into Visual Studio onto an environment with the SDK for 8.04 instead of 8.03.  None of the advice worked - the problem was in the web.client
I created a new version of Blazor Web App (in my case, I used 'with authentication') copied the web.client from there to the existing program, made the appropriate namespace changes and opened it.
I immediately saw that it used a UserInfo class and PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider.cs that I hadn't seen in the previous version, and I had to create the UserInfo class, but it cleared the error and the program runs fine.
I hated to shotgun it like this, but it beats deep-diving the structure of the  program.  I'm willing to bet that the problem in the older version is in those two files.
