Error deploying Blazor in 8.0 to a remote server
I try to publish Blazor and get this error:
The item "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" in item list "ResolvedFrameworkReference" does not define a value for metadata "RuntimePackPath"
I can't find any documentation on it - has anyone seen it before?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78254107/109941

This question is similar to: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I appreciate your positing those - they don't deal with the problem I'm having in 8.0

After researching for two days and trying dozens of fixes that didn't work, methodically backing them all out when they failed, I tried publishing from my laptop
It worked.
Sometimes I hate this job

The problem seemed to be in the SDK - I used Visual Studio Installer to modify VS and removed the current (8.03) SDK, then opened the project and it downloaded 8.04
This cleared the error but created a new one - where the web.client threw: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.
After chasing THAT for a day and following a lot of references to change a reference, I finally created a new project and took the web.client from it into the existing project.
This ended up removing 'PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider' and requiring that I create a UserInfo.cs with UserID and Email string properties, but the problems went away and the project uploads successfully to my site.
